# MongoDB: Is it possible to sort document by sub document values based on a condition

Tags: mongodb

Let's says we have the following documents:

```
{
    "Name" : "Steve",
    "Attributes" : [{
        "k" : 1,
        "v" : "Canada"
      }, {
        "k" : 2,
        "v" : "Toronto"
      }]
},
{
    "Name" : "John",
    "Attributes" : [{
        "k" : 1,
        "v" : "USA"
      }, {
        "k" : 2,
        "v" : "New-York"
      }]
},
{      
    "Name" : "Paul",
    "Attributes" : [{
        "k" : 1,
        "v" : "Canada"
      }, {
        "k" : 2,
        "v" : "Montreal"
      }]
}
```

What I want is to get all the documents where any attributes is equal to

```
{ "k":1, "v":"Canada" }
```

SORT BY attribute.v where attributes.k:2.

So the expected result should be:

```
{      
    "Name" : "Paul",
    "Attributes" : [{
        "k" : 1,
        "v" : "Canada"
      }, {
        "k" : 2,
        "v" : "Montreal"
      }]
},
{
    "Name" : "Steve",
    "Attributes" : [{
        "k" : 1,
        "v" : "Canada"
      }, {
        "k" : 2,
        "v" : "Toronto"
      }]
}
```

John is exclude because the k:1 value is USA not CANADA.
Paul comes first since in the k:2 value Montreal string came before Toronto string.

How can I achieved this? Either by a "standard" Mongo query or by an aggregation framework query

Comment: I've done a lot of experimentation. I just wanted to keep the thread as brief as possible. Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve this. This is why I asked the QUESTION! So, Can you do anything for me?

I see a complexity in this problem because I want to sort on the value of a field in a sub document on an Array based on a condition on another field of the sub document.

Comment: But have you looked at FAQ to see what kind of questions can be asked here?

Comment: Yes, I have you looked

Comment: You can use `$elemMatch` to do the query, but it only would return the matching array element. The sorting you want just isn't possible in MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks for your comment/answer @WiredPrairie. Do you think that this may be a "DB design smell" on my side? Let me explain. What I wanted to do is to add Custom attributes to an object and be able to query on those attributes and order the result by another attribute (All this in one mongo query). Currently I'm saving the attributes as a Dictionary<string, object> serialize with the option "DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments " which give me something like in my question { k : key, v : value }. Do you think there is another better way to save this kind of "Runtime/dynamic" informations?